# Awesomium.NET open links in default browser

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, web-controls, awesomium

I have problem with awesomium web control 1.7.4 in WPF , when the user click links in page , awesomium navigate to targetURL , but i want to open that links in system default browser.

also I want to determine mailto:jondue@example.com to open this links in default Email client.

Please help me.

Thanks

**Update :**

I've been doing some more searching to solve my problem, after few days I founded that when the link has a `target=_blank` the event `ShowCreatedWebView` is fired. The main problem was about links without `target=_blank`. After that I'm able to find links without that cause firing event `RequestBringIntoView`.

```
private void Browser_ShowCreatedWebView(object sender, Awesomium.Core.ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Browser.TargetURL.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

and

```
private void Browser_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.TargetURL != new Uri("about:blank"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Browser.TargetURL.AbsoluteUri);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should move your "Update" section into an answer. [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing some more searching to solve my problem, after few days I founded that when the link has a target=_blank the event ShowCreatedWebView is fired. The main problem was about links without target=_blank. After that I'm able to find links without that cause firing event RequestBringIntoView.

```
private void Browser_ShowCreatedWebView(object sender, Awesomium.Core.ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Browser.TargetURL.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

and

```
private void Browser_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (Browser.TargetURL != new Uri("about:blank"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Browser.TargetURL.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using IResourceInterceptor to decide what you want to do when Awesomium loads a page.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig());
        WebCore.Initialized += ((object sender, CoreStartEventArgs e) =>
        {
            WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new ResourceInterceptor("http://google.com/");
        });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


public class ResourceInterceptor : IResourceInterceptor
{
    //Url of the first page to be loaded inside webcontrol without redirection.
    protected string m_startupURL;

    public ResourceInterceptor(string startupURL)
    {
        m_startupURL = startupURL;
    }

    public virtual bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Url.ToString() != m_startupURL)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(request.Url.ToString());
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        return ResourceResponse.Create(request.Url.OriginalString);
    }
}
```

This is a very basic implementation. You should add some additional tests on the Url. Actually `Process.Start(request.Url.ToString())` can do anything (launching an application or formatting your disk). So don't forget to test whether it is a valid Url or a `mailto:` link.